# Drawing a line in excel using apache-poi

Tags: java, android, excel, line, apache-poi

Can anybody write me a few lines of code showing how to write a line in a cell in excel, using apache poi ?!
In plain Excel, I would go to Insert - Shapes - Line.
Basicaly, make code like this:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
Row row=sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
```

now, missing code would go here.
As i searched the net, I should be using Class HSSFSimpleShape and OBJECT_TYPE_LINE.
But i dont know how to implement it in my code :(

I guess I should have the cell which i want to draw the line in or some pixels as a coordinaets or something.

Help ! :)

Comment: Did you see this? I imagine that can help you to do the trick: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/poi/DrawingShapesExcelSheet.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Check out this example:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
HSSFPatriarch patriarch = (HSSFPatriarch) sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

/* Here is the thing: the line will go from top left in cell (0,0) to down left 
of cell (0,1) */
HSSFClientAnchor anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor(
  0, 0, 0, 255, (short) 0, 0,(short) 1, 0);

HSSFSimpleShape shape = patriarch.createSimpleShape(anchor);
shape.setShapeType(HSSFSimpleShape.OBJECT_TYPE_LINE);
shape.setLineStyleColor(10, 10, 10);
shape.setFillColor(90, 10, 200);
shape.setLineWidth(HSSFShape.LINEWIDTH_ONE_PT);
shape.setLineStyle(HSSFShape.LINESTYLE_SOLID);

// you don't even need the cell, but if you also want to write anything...
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("Test");
```

I also recommend to take a look at [HSSFClientAnchor Javadoc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFClientAnchor.html)

Comment: Hi any idea how to do the same using XSSF or SS usermodel?